# Windows 10 - won't stop asking for a password no matter the settings

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts

Windows 10 will just not stop asking me for a password now I've added my microsoft account to the damn thing.

I added my MS account as I wanted to backup my key ready for wiping and reinstalling fresh.

Now, no matter what the settings in `netplwiz` or via the control panels 'Sign In Options' are set to.

Right now netplwiz is unticked. - After doing this i entered my microsoft account details, as it was showing the 'local' username rather than my account and I knew that account didn't have a password at all, thinking that was what was breaking this whole thing. It accepted my password without quibble.

I went back into the control panel and my 'Sign In Option' has always been set to never ask, and still is showing never ask.

Now, if I lock, sleep or reboot the machine it asks me to re-enter the long (And rather complicated) password again. As multiple users use this account I'm not going to expect them to all memorise it, nor am I going to create accounts for them. Is there some other setting I'm missing somewhere? I've found if I simply *Remove* my account altogether it goes back to accepting the local user with the blank password, however this just makes the whole backing up the key thing stupid.

[Edit]

Ok, after re-entering the settings - rebooting now works as expected - it logs in automatically, but if the machine sleeps/is locked, it doesn't log back in, instead asking for the password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was going to suggest to disable/reenable for the netplwiz, because I know from experience that you can do this with a windows live account, though figuring out the username could sometimes be a problem.

You figured this out already, so here is the remaining question:

> Ok, after re-entering the settings - rebooting now works as expected - it logs in automatically, but if the machine sleeps/is locked, it doesn't log back in, instead asking for the password.

Yes, this is expected behavior. A computer gets locked when you lock or sleep. However, requiring a password at unlocking is a simple setting you can disable.

You can find it here:

Start Menu -> Settings (gear) -> Account -> Sign-In Options -> Require Sign-in.

Change this from "When PC Wakes up from Sleep" to "Never".

Comment: Yeah.... even with that option enabled, 'locking' the PC still does exactly that, however resuming from sleep is now ok. Is there someway to actually disable the lock behaviour? :D

Comment: I don't think there is one. Although with the new Creators update, you can actually make windows automatically unlock based on peripherals such as a nearby phone.

Comment: The only alternative I can think of is this: convert back to a local account, and remove the password.

Comment: Yeah might have to do this, bit silly that locking the screen with a local account with no password allows you to unlock easily, but the moment it's a ms account you can't :/

Comment: Not silly, its because you cannot set a passwordless ms account.

Comment: Ah, I'd argue it is, because it's a local account that's associated to a MS account @LPChip and you can't make changes to the MS account without entering the password for that, anyway :). Basically, either account username+password, should work and log in and then require the MS account for MS account changes. Either way accepted as the answer, as you're right about it locking when locked.